# Why does the SVG diagram behave differently in the generated PDF than in the browser?

Tags: pdf, svg, pdf-generation, apache-fop

I want to generate a diagram based on some previously calculated data. The diagram should be on a PDF along with further information. Apache Fop 2.0 is used for PDF generation but the generated PDF looks different than the SVG in the browser.

- SVG: [image: SVG]
- PDF [image: PDF]

The SVG graphic looks the same in all tested browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox). I already tried inserting the SVG-code inside a `fo:instream-foreign-object` tag or include the seperate file with `fo:external-graphic` but both variants behave the same. I also tried to export the SVG image to another format such as PNG but the exported image looks like the PDF-version too.

What do I have to change so that the SVG graphic behaves the same in the browser and the generated PDF?

This is the generated `.svg`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="800" version="1.1" viewport="0 0 1000 800">
    <g>
        <!--Styles-->
        <style>
            .x { font: bold 12pt sans-serif; } .y { font: bold 12pt sans-serif; } .title { font: 12pt sans-serif; }
        </style>
        <!--Grid-->
        <defs>
            <pattern id="grid" width="67" height="23" x="100" y="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <path fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="0.5" d="M 67 0 L 0 0 0  23"/>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <g transform="translate(0,800) scale(1,-1)" x="100" y="100">
            <rect width="800" height="600" x="100" y="100" fill="url(#grid)"/>
        </g>
        <!--X-Achse-->
        <line x1="100" x2="900" y1="700" y2="700" style="stroke:black"/>
        <text class="title" dx="500" dy="750" text-anchor="middle">
            Abstand in mm
        </text>
        <!--Y-Achse-->
        <line x1="100" x2="100" y1="100" y2="700" style="stroke:black"/>
        <text class="title" dx="20" dy="400" text-anchor="middle" writing-mode="tb">
            Last in kg
        </text>
        <!--X-Text-->
        <text class="x" dx="100" dy="725" text-anchor="middle">
            0
        </text>
        <text class="x" dx="167" dy="725" text-anchor="middle">
            100
        </text>
        <text class="x" dx="234" dy="725" text-anchor="middle">
            200
        </text>
        <text class="x" dx="301" dy="725" text-anchor="middle">
            300
        </text>
        <text class="x" dx="368" dy="725" text-anchor="middle">
            400
        </text>
        <text class="x" dx="435" dy="725" text-anchor="middle">
            500
        </text>
        <text class="x" dx="502" dy="725" text-anchor="middle">
            600
        </text>
        <text class="x" dx="569" dy="725" text-anchor="middle">
            700
        </text>
        <text class="x" dx="636" dy="725" text-anchor="middle">
            800
        </text>
        <text class="x" dx="703" dy="725" text-anchor="middle">
            900
        </text>
        <text class="x" dx="770" dy="725" text-anchor="middle">
            1000
        </text>
        <text class="x" dx="837" dy="725" text-anchor="middle">
            1100
        </text>
        <!--Y-Text-->
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="698" text-anchor="end">
            0
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="672" text-anchor="end">
            1000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="646" text-anchor="end">
            2000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="620" text-anchor="end">
            3000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="594" text-anchor="end">
            4000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="568" text-anchor="end">
            5000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="542" text-anchor="end">
            6000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="516" text-anchor="end">
            7000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="490" text-anchor="end">
            8000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="464" text-anchor="end">
            9000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="438" text-anchor="end">
            10000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="412" text-anchor="end">
            11000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="386" text-anchor="end">
            12000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="360" text-anchor="end">
            13000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="334" text-anchor="end">
            14000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="308" text-anchor="end">
            15000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="282" text-anchor="end">
            16000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="256" text-anchor="end">
            17000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="230" text-anchor="end">
            18000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="204" text-anchor="end">
            19000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="178" text-anchor="end">
            20000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="152" text-anchor="end">
            21000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="126" text-anchor="end">
            22000
        </text>
        <text class="y" dx="90" dy="100" text-anchor="end">
            23000
        </text>
        <!--Chart-->
        <polyline fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" points="106.208955223881,114.686956521739 121.731343283582,114.686956521739 137.373134328358,114.686956521739 153.014925373134,114.686956521739 168.65671641791,114.686956521739 184.298507462687,114.686956521739 199.940298507463,114.686956521739 215.582089552239,114.686956521739 231.223880597015,114.686956521739 246.865671641791,114.686956521739 262.507462686567,114.686956521739 278.149253731343,114.686956521739 293.791044776119,114.686956521739 309.432835820896,114.686956521739 325.074626865672,114.686956521739 340.716417910448,114.686956521739 356.358208955224,114.686956521739 372,114.686956521739 387.641791044776,114.686956521739 403.283582089552,114.686956521739 418.925373134328,114.686956521739 434.567164179104,114.686956521739 450.208955223881,114.686956521739 465.850746268657,114.686956521739 481.492537313433,114.686956521739 497.134328358209,114.686956521739 512.656716417911,114.686956521739 528.298507462687,114.686956521739 543.940298507463,114.686956521739 559.582089552239,114.686956521739 575.223880597015,114.686956521739 590.865671641791,114.686956521739 606.507462686567,114.686956521739 622.149253731343,114.686956521739 637.791044776119,114.686956521739 653.432835820896,114.686956521739 669.074626865672,114.686956521739 684.716417910448,114.686956521739 700.358208955224,114.686956521739 716,114.686956521739 731.641791044776,114.686956521739 747.283582089552,114.686956521739 762.925373134328,114.686956521739 778.567164179104,147.4 794.208955223881,189.660869565217 809.850746268657,225.921739130435 825.492537313433,257.382608695652 841.134328358209,284.904347826087 856.776119402985,309.217391304348 894.029850746269,357.060869565217 "/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

This is my `.fo`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master
  margin-right="1.5cm"
  margin-left="1.5cm"
  margin-bottom="2cm"
  margin-top="1cm"
  page-width="21cm"
  page-height="29.7cm"
  master-name="first">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="1cm"/>
      <fo:region-before extent="1cm"/>
      <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>

  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="first">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
      <fo:block line-height="14pt" font-size="10pt"
    text-align="end">Embedding SVG examples</fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
      <fo:block line-height="14pt" font-size="10pt"
    text-align="end">Page <fo:page-number/></fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>

    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

      <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold" font-size="14pt" space-before.optimum="3pt" space-after.optimum="15pt">
      Embedding SVG
      </fo:block>

      <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic src="file:out.svg" width="100%" content-height="100%" content-width="scale-down-to-fit" scaling="uniform"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problen using the attributes `x` and `y` instead of `dx` and `dy` on the text elements.

Comment: This may be an issue with Apache Fop, in which case you should report it to that library's issue tracker.